# Custom post type taxonomy not being replaced in ACF post object field output

Tags: wordpress, twig, permalinks, timber

I have a custom post type (Photos) and a taxonomy (Locations) setup on my client's website. The permalinks work correctly when accessed using the menus, search, and directly from the custom post type in the WordPress admin panel, but not when accessing them using an Advanced Custom Fields post object field in my Timber/Twig template. The taxonomy portion (`%locations%`) of the URL is not being replaced. For example, [http://example.com/photos/`%locations%`/taj-mahal-and-the-ganges/](http://example.com/photos/%60%locations%%60/taj-mahal-and-the-ganges/). The `%locations%` should be replaced with **world** and **india**, which are locations from the custom taxonomy.

The post's custom post object field is being pulled into the template using the following code: `<a href="{{ story.meta( 'associated_photo_gallery' ).link }}" class="view-gallery">{{ __('View photo gallery', textdomain) }}</a>`.

I have included my custom post type and taxonomy code below:

```
function textdomain_register_photos_post_type() {
  $args = [
    'label' => 'Photo Galleries',
    'labels' => [ 
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Photo Gallery', 'singular' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Photo Galleries', 'admin menu' ),
        'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Photo Galleries', 'admin bar' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'add new' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Photo Gallery' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Photo Gallery' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Photo Gallery' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Photo Gallery' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Photo Galleries' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Photo Galleries' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'No photo galleries found.' ),
    ],
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'thumbnail'
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-gallery',
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'taxonomies' => [ 'locations', ],
    'has_archive' => true,
    'delete_with_user' => false,
    'rewrite' => [
        'slug' => 'photos/%locations%',
        'with_front' => false,
    ],
];
register_post_type( 'photos', $args );
};
add_action( 'init', 'textdomain_register_photos_post_type' );

function textdomain_register_locations_taxonomy() {
  $args = [
    'labels' => [
        'name' => _x( 'Locations', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Location', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Locations' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Locations' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Location' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Location:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Location' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Location' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Location' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Location Name' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Locations' ),
    ],
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => [
        'slug' => 'locations',
        'hierarchical' => true,
    ],
];
register_taxonomy( 'locations', [ 'photos' ], $args );
};
add_action( 'init', 'textdomain_register_locations_taxonomy' );

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'textdomain_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
function textdomain_post_type_link( $post_link, $post ) {
  // Bail out if not photos post type.
  if ( 'photos' !== $post->post_type ) {
    return $post_link;
  }

  $taxonomy = 'locations';
  $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy );
  $slug = [];

  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    if ( $term->parent == 0 ) {
      array_unshift( $slug, sanitize_title_with_dashes( $term->name ) );
    } else {
      array_push( $slug, sanitize_title_with_dashes( $term->name ) );
    }
  }

  if ( ! empty( $slug ) ) {
    $post_link = str_replace( '%' . $taxonomy . '%', join( '/', $slug ), $post_link );
  }
  return $post_link;
}
```

I have saved my permalinks multiple times and have `flush_rewrite_rules();` at the bottom of my theme's functions file.

**Update**

WordPress is displaying this warning `Invalid argument supplied foreach()` on line 422 of the functions.php file. The code is as follows:

```
$taxonomy = 'locations';
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy );
$slug = [];

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
  if ( $term->parent == 0 ) {
    array_unshift( $slug, sanitize_title_with_dashes( $term->name ) );
  } else {
    array_push( $slug, sanitize_title_with_dashes( $term->name ) );
  }
}
```

I am not sure if this could be causing the issue, but my PHP knowledge is limited.

Any tips or suggestions on this issue are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your str replace needs to be updated to: `$post_link = str_replace( '%locations%', join( '/', $slug ), $post_link );`

Comment: @mikerojas Unfortunately that does not apply. The taxonomy is set as a variable further up in the code. See `$taxonomy = 'locations';`. I also tried hard coding, but it did not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue was related to how the post ID was being retrieved for the taxonomies. I reviewed the [get_the_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/#source) function reference and found that `get_the_ID()` needed to be replaced by `$post->ID` in the following line: `$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );`. My updated and working function is below.

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'textdomain_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
function textdomain_post_type_link( $post_link, $post ) {
  // Bail out if not photos post type.
  if ( 'photos' !== $post->post_type ) {
    return $post_link;
  }

  $taxonomy = 'locations';
  // Replaced get_the_ID() with $post->ID
  $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
  $slug = [];

  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    if ( $term->parent == 0 ) {
      array_unshift( $slug, sanitize_title_with_dashes( $term->name ) );
    } else {
      array_push( $slug, sanitize_title_with_dashes( $term->name ) );
    }
  }

  if ( ! empty( $slug ) ) {
    $post_link = str_replace( '%' . $taxonomy . '%', join( '/', $slug ), $post_link );
  }
  return $post_link;
}
```